# Can't load database in ASP.NET MVC 5 using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I was looking for an answer but I couldn't find any (although I found similar questions)..

I'm going through an ASP.NET MVC tutorial ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)), and when I run the app, the home page loads fine, but when I try to load localdb, I get following message:

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /Students

My connection string:

```
<add name="SchoolContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I have same connection string in my web forms application and everything is working fine.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give your application pool right permissions to database file? Can you login with SQL Server Management Studio to that database? Have you registered it (Database)?

Your database is a file and it looks like your IIS Application pool user (on MVC application) doesn't have access "read" permissions. Try to give it.

Most problems are covered in this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis/